# IIS URL Rewriting - Rule captures despite file existing

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I've got a rule that rewrites URLs unless a physical file exists (so static files can be returned) - however for some reason the rules get rewritten anyway, to much frustration.

Here's my Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Front Page">
                <match url="/?" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/Home/FrontPage" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Map Everything" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"      negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="EntryPoint.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>

        </rules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it turns out the "Front Page" rule was the problem, and the rule "/?" was matching everything when I should have used "^$" instead.

After fixing that, the IsFile/IsDirectory rules were being respected.